# listing png files in folder

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to make a list of all png files in a folder that contains other folders. Here's my code.

```
import os
filelist=os.listdir('images')
for fichier in filelist:
    if not(fichier.endswith(".png")):
        filelist.remove(fichier)
print(filelist)
```

problem is, that last print shows that some of the subfolders (but not all) escaped the culling...

```
['aa.png', 'Nouveau dossier - Copie', 'Nouveau dossier - Copie (3)', 'Nouveau dossier - Copie (5)', 'zz.png']
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You can use glob to search for files. https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Summary: **Never, ever, ever** modify the list that you are iterating over.

Instead, iterate over a copy:

```
import os
filelist=os.listdir('images')
for fichier in filelist[:]: # filelist[:] makes a copy of filelist.
    if not(fichier.endswith(".png")):
        filelist.remove(fichier)
print(filelist)
```

Or if you don't like to make unnecessary copies, iterate in reverse (this will only work if you can guarantee that the items in the list are unique; for a file system this is a good assumption):

```
for fichier in reversed(filelist):
    # do stuff
```

Note that you can use Python's `glob` module to simplify this:

```
import glob
print(glob.glob('images/*.png'))
```

### The reason why

When you iterate over a list in Python, behind the scenes Python is actually iterating over the indices of the list.  You can see that this is a huge problem whenever you actually remove the items:

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 3]:
for x in l:
    if x%2 == 0:
        l.remove(x)
    print('x == {}'.format(x))
print('l == {}'.format(l))
```

You can tell by what is printed here that the second 2 is skipped, and that `l` has a value of `[1, 2, 3]`.  This is because, whenever the first 2 is reached and removed, the index is `1` (the second element).  On the next iteration, the index is `2`.  At this point, `l == [1,2,3]`, so `x == 3`.  If you run the code, it will probably be more obvious than this explanation.

Comment: Thank you, this explains why it doesn't work. Should have seen it.

Answer (score 20):

You shouldn't modify lists while iterating over them. It causes funny stuff to happen.

Best use a list comprehension instead:

```
filelist= [file for file in os.listdir('images') if file.endswith('.png')]
```

Comment: the same concept can be applied to the initial approach, just replace the remove-step. However, this is more pythonic

Comment: Yep, I always forget you can do that in python.