# Open random png image from a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Hello i need help with a very simple Python 3 script. In the script i try open a png image file from a folder with this:

```
png = Image.open('img/image.png', + 'r')
```

It's work good, but now i need get random .png images from same folder, but after some unsuccessful try, I'll like know how do it, actually i use in my script

- from random import randint
- import uuid
- from PIL import Image

Any help will be appreciated, thank you all

Comment: Can you show the exact code you tried, and describe how exactly it failed (exception, unexpected results, etc)?

Comment: [List all the `.png` in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27593246/7501501) then [pick a random item from the list](https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/).

Comment: Get a list of the file names in the folder with `glob.glob()` and then use `random.choice()` to pick one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import glob
import random
from PIL import Image
img = random.choice(glob.glob('img/*.png'))
png = Image.open(img, + 'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os,random
from PIL import Image
random_image = random.choice(os.listdir("img"))
Image.open(random_image)
```